# optimización de consulta sql perzonalizada

Tags: php, mysql, charts

Hola amigos quería ayuda sobre como podría optimizar esta consulta, ya que la ocupo para hacer 3 tipo de gráficas, las cuales tarda al rededor de 45 seg obteniendo la información del día.
y la grafico de esa manera.
[image: imagen]

```
select b.nombre as AP, 
COUNT(DISTINCT(a.idCliente)) as conectados, 
SUM(c.visitors) as visitantes, 
SUM(c.parserby) as transeuntes 
FROM logsclientes as a 
INNER JOIN dispositivos as b on a.idDispositivoSucursal = b.idDispositivoSucursal 
INNER JOIN consultas_diarias as c on b.idSucursalUO = c.idsucursal 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(a.FechaConexion,'%Y-%m-%d') = curdate() 
and DATE_FORMAT(c.fecha,'%Y-%m-%d') = curdate() 
and b.idSucursalUO = '1' 
AND c.idsucursal = '1' 
GROUP BY b.idDispositivoSucursal 
ORDER BY `conectados`  DESC
```

Podrían ayudarme a realizarla de otro modo o como podría mejorar.

Feliz día.